# What are cause executeUpdate to remain executable for long time until kill the db sessions?

Tags: java, spring, database, multithreading, locking

I have valid update statement using below code but when call function executeUpdate()for some reasons it keep executing until kill session !!

this block of code executed once at time , as I am locking these block of code until each thread finish then I start other thread.

but for some reason I can`t acquire lock because previous thread is stack as we didn`t get any response for specific value only, where other condition value are executed normally !!

```
StringBuilder updateQuery = new StringBuilder();
updateQuery.append("update appL set user = :userId");
updateQuery.append(" where user is null and app_id in (:appIds)");

Query updateQueryToExecute = entityManager.createNativeQuery(updateQuery.toString());

updateQueryToExecute.setParameter("userId", 1).setParameter("appIds", appIds);

updateQueryToExecute.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT).executeUpdate();
```

Please note that this statement can be executed successfully most of time, it stuck only with specific value for where condition!